# Movable object design in Haskell

Tags: data-structures, haskell

Suppose I have an object which has a point denoting it's location and shape.

```
type Point = (Double, Double)

data Object =
    Object { location :: Point
           , shape    :: Shape }
```

where a shape might be like

```
data Shape
    = Circle { radius :: Double }
    | Rectangle { height :: Double, width :: Double }
```

Suppose I have a function which can draw objects.

```
draw :: [Object] -> IO ()
```

So far here are no problems.

Now, suppose I want objects to move. So objects should have a velocity.

```
type Velocity = (Double, Double)

data Object =
    Object { location :: (Double, Double)
           , shape    :: Shape
           , velocity :: Velocity }

type Time = Double

move    :: Time ->  Object  ->  Object
moveAll :: Time -> [Object] -> [Object]
```

The problem is that I need a velocity field to move objects, but I don't need
it to draw them.

I think that allowing `draw` function to know about object's velocity breaks
abstraction. Am I right?

How to combine previous object definition with extra velocity field in order
to move objects?

- To use tuples like `(Velocity, Object)`?
- To wrap both into new data type? If so, then how to call that data type?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: One option would be to have something like `MovableObject` that contains `Object` plus its velocity. Most of the time it's better to have a dedicated, named data type rather than using tuples. Whether or not making velocity available to `draw` depends on what exactly you want to draw. For example if you decide to draw arrows representing velocity, it would be appropriate.

Comment: `lens` provides tools to interact with deeply nested data structures.

Comment: I'd suggest hiding details using a type class, I think that's the cleanest simple solution. It's not a trivial problem, it manifests in widget-based GUIs too.

Nevertheless, providing velocities to the rendering system is commonplace as a debugging aid. As an example, in pang-a-lambda (a game I've been working on, I've posted videos online) these are shown by default to make sure collisions work as expected. If you want a reference, I remember reading about this in Jason Gregory's Game Engine Architecture (probably in chapters 10 or 12).

Comment: Thanks for comments and answers! I like the type class solution mentioned by @IvanPerez because it allows to list properties which rendering system needs without worrying about how data was designed. I'll accept an answer like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a typeclass for objects that know their location and shape, and create an instance for `Object`.  Then your `draw` would accept any instance of that typeclass, but wouldn't be able to find out about any other fields in `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

Besides using tuples or wrapping `Object` in a new datatype, another option is to parameterize `Object` with a type variable:

```
data Object v =
    Object { location :: (Double, Double)
           , shape    :: Shape
           , velocity :: v } deriving (Functor)
```

When passing an object to the renderer, you could "mute" the velocity by storing a `()`, using [`void myObject`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:void) or perhaps using a polymorphic update like `myObject { velocity = () }`.

Comment: If the renderer has type `[Object v] -> IO ()`, then you know that it cannot use the fact that whenever you call it you actually pass a `[Object Velocity]`, and there is no need for void.